# Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request when indexing process is executes

Tags: java, solr

I change info in my solr.xml and monitor.xml files ,make reindex and see next

my cmd:

```
D:\solr-4.6.0\solr-4.6.0\example\exampledocs>java -jar post.jar solr.xml monitor.xml
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file solr.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 fo
r URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
POSTing file monitor.xml
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 Bad Request
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 fo
r URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/update
2 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
Time spent: 0:00:00.061
```

After it if I make `q=*:*` - I don't see new field at these documents.

What do I wrong?

Comment: This is the SimplePostTool log...could you post the SOLR log too? What is monitor.xml? One of the example file supplied with the download bundle? What kind of change you did on your solr.xml?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From the log, its look like you made some changes into solr.xml/monitor.xml file which resides into /solr/example/exampledocs folder. You can just replace that file again with original files from solr.zip